# CiviCRM Home says CURL is not installed but it is

Tags: wordpress

CivCRM version 4.6
PHP Version 5.6
CURL was installed with `apt install php-curl`

The CiviCRM home page insists that CURL is not installed but all indications are that is is installed. My phpinfo() shows that is it is. I can execute it from the command line.

I've searched for solutions but can't find it yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CiviCRM has [detected that the function `curl_init` is not available](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/d799e82070e2319bb5b2e580fabf90f64f907010/CRM/Utils/HttpClient.php#L112), and is showing a warning.

Commandline `phpinfo()` will show changes immediately (since PHP is started for each execution), while PHP in the webserver needs you to restart it separately to pick up new PHP modules. (These modes of running PHP also have different configurations loaded per default - but apt should already have enabled `curl` for each.)

You can verify this by checking `phpinfo` through the webserver (eg in Drupal, visit `admin/reports/status/php`; in WordPress you might need to [use this phpinfo plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-php-info/) or just create a `phpinfo` file in your site. If you see curl missing there, it could be a reload is all you need.

Depending on your webserver configuration (PHP can run as FPM, mod_php, etc), you'll need to restart the service (eg apache2, php-fpm) which runs PHP on your server. Most likely,

```
sudo service <your php service> reload
```

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/6358/how-do-you-restart-apache
- https://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm

Comment: Reloading php-fpm did the trick. On my system I'm running two versions of php. I issued the following:

    sudo service php7.0-fpm  reload

There was no separate service for 5.6 but this worked.

Comment: Dumb question but how do I found out what to put in `<your php service>`. cUrl was already installed before I installed CiviCRM but I'm getting this message anyways and want to see if this still helps.

Comment: Hi Christia! `service` is a command to manage running daemons, and (assuming a particular kind of *nix/distro, anyway) you can list the services installed on your system with `sudo service --status-all`. Likely candidates are `php5-fpm`, `php7.0-fpm` etc. In the absence of any php-ish things, probably you want `apache2` or `httpd` ... but look for PHP services first :)

Comment: Thanks! `service apache2 reload` worked for me. Edit: or not. I'll post a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

if you're running apache, did you restart it after installing php-curl?

Comment: You put it far more succinctly than I did 

Comment: but you showed citations and details. I think you won :)

Comment: Yes but I did not restart php-fpm which I will do when I get back to this project